# Python 2.7 single executable for python kivy GUI with PyInstaller

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller

I am trying unsuccessfully to wrap up my kivy GUI application into a single executable with pyinstaller.  Whey I run PyInstaller, it creates a single executable, but when I run it I get a "fatal error" saying "Failed to execute script myApp". I am using python 2.7 on windows.  Here is my directory setup:

```
GUI_DEV\
    -myApp_style.kv  (this is my kivy file)
    -myApp.py (this is my main script)
    -ico.ico  (this is my icon file)
    -myImage.png  (this is an image used by myApp.py)
    rel\
        -myApp.spec  (this is the spec file I am using with pyinstaller)
```

Here is my myApp.py code:

```
import kivy
#kivy.require("1.9.0")
from kivy.core.window import Window 
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
import sys, os

def resourcePath():
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS)

    return os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."))

Builder.load_file('myApp.kv')

class designerLayout(GridLayout):
    part = "123"
    def update(self):
        self.part = value
        self.id_test.text = "hello world: "+str(self.part)    
        return

    def spinner_clicked(self, value):
        self.part = value
        self.id_test.text = "hello world: "+str(self.part)    

class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (1,1,1,1)
        Window.size = (930,780)
        return designerLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   kivy.resources.resource_add_path(resourcePath()) # add this line
   calcApp = myApp()

calcApp = myApp()
calcApp.run()
```

Here is my myApp.spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python -*- 
from kivy.deps import sdl2, glew
block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['..\\myApp.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\GUI_DEV\\rel\\MyHiddenImports'],
             binaries=None,
             datas=None,
             hiddenimports=['MyHiddenImports'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)

a.datas += [('myApp_style.kv', '../myApp_style.kv', 'DATA')]

exe = EXE(pyz, Tree('C:\\GUI_DEV\\','Data'),
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
          name='myApp',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=False, icon='C:\\GUI_DEV\\ico.ico' )
```

I am then running the command:

`python -m PyInstaller myApp.spec`

from the GUI_DEV\rel directory.

Any ideas as to why this is not working?  I am not getting any errors that point me to any specific problems.

Comment: Can you make this a bit more Minimal? See how to make a [mcve]. For the most part though, this is a good question.

Comment: Just a possibility, but in my experience I have had to include my images in the `a.datas`. The `icon` is already specified, so try adding `myImage.png` to

Comment: If the above suggestion does not work, try building in `one directory` mode to see if everything needed is in the produced directory.

Comment: John, adding the images to a.datas got rid of the fatal errors and the app runs now.  The image is the wrong size and in the different place when I run the generated executable versus the .py script, but at least it runs.  Thanks.